# Añadir metodo para lista generica sin modificar las clases

Tags: c#

He añadido estos métodos a la clase List

```
        public static bool Importar(this List<j2Datos.Cliente> lista, j2Datos.Cliente obj)
        {
        if (lista.Where(o=>o.clave==obj.clave).Count()>0)
            return false;
        lista.Add(obj);
        return true;
        }
    public static bool Importar(this List<j2Datos.Provincia> lista, j2Datos.Provincia obj)
        {
        if (lista.Where(o => o.clave == obj.clave).Count() > 0)
            return false;
        lista.Add(obj);
        return true;
        }
    public static bool Importar(this List<j2Datos.Localidad> lista, j2Datos.Localidad obj)
        {
        if (lista.Where(o => o.clave == obj.clave).Count() > 0)
            return false;
        lista.Add(obj);
        return true;
        }
```

Hacen exactamente lo mismo, antes de añadirlos a la lista comprobar si el campo clave del objeto ya esta.

Como estos tres tengo varios mas exactamente igual. Todos los objetos que quiero añadir tienen el campo clave
Los objetos son instancias generadas con EF data base first, por lo que no puedo editarlas.

Hay alguna forma de hacer uno genérico, y que de igual el tipo lista  y objeto que le pase y que haga lo mismo en vez de tener 10 métodos?

Gracias

Comment: Yo probaria declarando los parametros de entrada como "Object", en vez de tus clases especificas. De esa manera lo unificas y podes pasarle cualquier tipo de objeto.

Comment: Lo había pensado pero como le dices que un "Object" tiene una clave en la where?

Comment: @Juanjo Si es posible modifica la pregunta para agregar la limitación respecto a la herencia, ahí modifique la respuesta agregando una solución con `Reflection`

Comment: Lo pregunte en un comentario en la respuesta pero no contestaste nada.. EF no define las clases como partial?

Comment: @gbianchi mañana te lo confirmo, ahora mismo no estoy en el ordenador

Comment: Si es asi, podes aplicar tranquilamente la solucion con interfaces

Comment: Es cierto, pero me parece mucho más trabajo, genera el interfaz,y luego cada una clases parciales.... Más sencillo por reflexión, y por eficiencia no creo que las listas tengan más de 4 o 5  elementos

Comment: Reflexion es mas lento. Siempre... la otra version ademas de mas rapida, es logica.

Comment: Mañana te digo cómo es la clase, pero ya te digo, el rendimiento no me preocupa mucho, no está en un "proceso importante", lo uso en un paso previo para convertir un list en un datatable (con refelexion), y tampoco tarda mucho en convertir una lista con 30 elementos

Comment: las clases, efectivamente, se definen como partial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenes que usar una [**interface**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface), [**herencia**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance) y [**generics**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) para lograr lo que buscas.

Supongamos que tenes la siguiente interface

```
public interface IConClave
{        
    string Clave { get; set; }
}
```

Todas las clases que implementen esta interface, deberán cumplir la regla de implementar la propiedad `Clave`.

Teniendo esto en cuenta, definimos las siguientes clases que implementan la interface `IConClave`

```
public class Provincia : IConClave
{        
    public string NombreProvincia { get; set; }
    public string Clave { get; set; }
}

public class Pais : IConClave
{
    public string NombrePais { get; set; }
    public string Clave { get; set; }
}
```

Ya con esto, tenemos 2 clases que implementan la interface `IConClave` por lo que ambas definen la propiedad `Clave`

Ahora, se hace necesario el uso de una función genérica, que para implementarla, lo hacemos de la siguiente manera

```
public static class Extension
{        
    public static bool Importar<T>(this List<T> lista, T objetoGenerico)
        where T : IConClave
    {
        if(lista.Where(o => o.Clave == objetoGenerico.Clave).Count()!=0)
        {
            lista.Add(objetoGenerico);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior `T` es un tipo que debe ser inferido, si observas, después de la definición de la cabecera del método

```
public static bool Importar<T>(this List<T> lista, T objetoGenerico)
```

Utilizo la condición `where T : IConClave` por lo que esta función sólo podrá ser llamada por una `List<T>` si y solo si `T` es una clase que implemente la interface `IConClave`.

Teniendo en cuenta, que si o si debe implementar la interface, eso implica, que `T` va a tener la propiedad `Clave`, por lo que puedo realizar la validación que buscas de manera genérica.

Luego, a la función la llamarías como a cualquier otro método de extensión

```
List<Provincia> Provincias = new List<Provincia>();
Provincias.Importar(new Provincia { Clave = "0", NombreProvincia = "Mendoza" });


List<Pais> Paises = new List<Pais>();
Paises.Importar(new Pais { Clave = "0", NombrePais = "Argentina" });
```

---

**EDIT**: dado lo que planteas en el comentario (no es posible modificar las clases `Cliente`, `Provincia` y `Localidad`, la solución podría darse usando [reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection)

En este ejemplo, las clases `Provincia` y `Pais` serían las mismas, con la única diferencia que no heredarían `IConClave`

```
public class Provincia
{        
    public string NombreProvincia { get; set; }
    public string Clave { get; set; }
}

public class Pais
{
    public string NombrePais { get; set; }
    public string Clave { get; set; }
}
```

Haciendo uso de Reflection, podría crearse una extensión como la siguiente:

```
public static class Extension
    {
        public static bool Importar<T>(this List<T> lista, T objetoGenerico)            
        {
            PropertyInfo Propiedad = typeof(T).GetProperty("Clave");

            if(Propiedad != null)
            {
                string claveObjetoGenerico = Propiedad.GetValue(objetoGenerico) as string;

                foreach(T elemento in lista)
                {                    
                    string claveElementoLista = Propiedad.GetValue(elemento) as string;

                    if (string.Equals(claveObjetoGenerico,claveElementoLista))
                    {
                        lista.Add(objetoGenerico);
                        return true;
                    }                                            
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Paso a explicar su funcionamiento, en este caso, la función genérica, podrá llamarse con cualquier `List<T>`, por lo que lo primero que hago, es intentar obtener el objeto `PropertyInfo` de la propiedad `Clave`, que de no existir, la función finaliza devolviendo `false`.

En caso de que efectivamente la propiedad exista, obtengo su valor con [PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) y la comparo con cada una de las propiedades `Clave` dentro de la lista.

Comment: Es lo que estaba buscando, el problema es las clases provincia, localidad, etc las "importo" de un EntityFramework con dabasefirst, entonces no puedo tocar las clases, si no cada vez que actualizo el modelo tendre que reconstruirlo todo, pero te lo he dado como buena la respuesta

Comment: @Juanjo dado lo que comentas de database first, la solución la podrías encarar usando reflection, lo malo, es que no vas a poder manejar la accesibilidad del método para que intellisense sólo lo recomiende cuando debe, me explico?

Comment: @Juanjo ahí modifique la respuesta para que puedas solucionar tu problemática sin modificar las clases, porfavor, edita la pregunta original agregando esta limitación, así otra persona puede dar con la solución

Comment: @Juanjo EF define las clases completas, o como partial?

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta. Muchas gracias. Era justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

Quiero compartir con vosotros mi solución completa gracias a la solución a de @Juan Salvador Portugal y @gbianchi

Lo primero que he hecho ha sido crear un intefaz en el mismo proyecto donde tengo la clases que genera EF:

```
public interface IConClave
    {
    int Clave { get; }
    }
```

Luego he añadido este interfaz a las clases (que son partial) que necesito usar "importar":

```
public partial class Provincia : IConClave
    {
    public int Clave { get => this.clave; }
    }
public partial class Localidad : IConClave
    {
    public int Clave { get => this.clave; }
    }
public partial class Estado : IConClave
    {
    public int Clave { get => this.clave; }
    }
```

En mi caso todas las clases tienen la propiedad clase y no Clase, y como solo necesito que sea de lectura no me hace falta el set, y en el get devuelvo la propiedad "clave"

Y por ultimo:

```
public static class ListExtensiones
    {
    public static bool Importar<T>(this List<T> lista, T objetoGenerico)
            where T : IConClave
        {
        if (lista.Where(o => o.Clave == objetoGenerico.Clave).Count() == 0)
            {
            lista.Add(objetoGenerico);
            return true;
            }
        else
            {
            return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Gracias